# QML WebView.back does not work

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

In QML I want to use WebView , but the WebView.back does not work.
Is there some way how to navigate, or do I have to store all the previous paths and navigate between them manualy using javascript function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use WebView [goBack()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtwebkit-webview.html#goBack-method) instead of just "back". The following code shows how to use it in a very minimal browser:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtWebKit 3.0

Rectangle {
    id: mainRect
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    Button {
        id: backButton
        text: "Back"
        onClicked: {
            if (webview.canGoBack) {
                webview.goBack()
            }
        }
    }
    WebView {
        id: webview
        url: "http://askubuntu.com"
        anchors {
            top: backButton.bottom
            bottom: mainRect.bottom
            left: mainRect.left
            right: mainRect.right
        }
    }
}
```